# Given two numbers represented by two lists, write a function that returns sum list

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

Suppose you have two linked list **5->4 ( 4 5 )** and **5->4->3 ( 3 4 5)** you have to return a resultant linked list **0->9->3 (3 9 0)**.

```
/*struct Node
{
int data;
Node* next;
}; */

Node*  addTwoLists(Node* first, Node* second){
int sum = 0, carry = 0;
Node *three, *temp, *prev;

three = new Node;
temp = three;

while(first!=NULL || second!=NULL) {
    sum = carry + (first?first->data:0+second?second->data:0);
    carry = sum/10;

    temp->data = sum;
    temp->next = new Node;
    prev = temp;
    temp = temp->next;

    first = first->next;
    second = second->next;
}

    if(carry > 0) {
        temp->data = carry;
        temp->next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        delete temp;
        prev->next = NULL;
    }   
return three;
```

}

I am getting Run Time Error(Code Dumped) for the above code.

Comment: Welcome to SO, the provide source code doesn't compile (`prev` is not defined). Could you provide a ["Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: In the while-loop, to store only one digit, you should assign `temp->data = (sum % 10);` instead of `temp->data = sum;`.

Comment: Try debugging the code! see it yourself and let people know what you found by editing your post.